# AWS AppSync - amplify codegen types not creating anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've used the AWS Console to put together an AppSync API that uses resolvers to write to an RDB. I've set up the codegen with `amplify add codegen --apiId myId` but when I run `amplify codegen types`, there is no console output and I can't see any types being created in my project.

I understand that I need these auto-generated types when I try to [run queries](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/codegen#queries-1). Should this be working? Where would I expect to see the types get created? I see the introspection schema at `app\src\main\graphql\schema.json` but I don't see any `.java` or `.kt` files getting created.

This is my `.graphqlconfig.yml`:

```
projects:
  FocalistTest1:
    schemaPath: app/src/main/graphql/schema.json
    includes:
      - app/src/main/graphql/**/*.graphql
    excludes:
      - ./amplify/**
    extensions:
      amplify:
        codeGenTarget: ''
        generatedFileName: ''
        docsFilePath: app/src/main/graphql/com/amazonaws/amplify/generated/graphql
        region: us-east-2
        apiId: [snipped]
        maxDepth: 2
extensions:
  amplify:
    version: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derp. Found them in the generated files section after a build. I had been checking the git files to see if the command had created anything, but they must be under an ignored folder.

Answer (score 1):

The generatedFileName is empty.  That should be set to a path to the target file that you want `generatedFileName: 'path/to/file'`.